# Opacity transitions in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to implement a simple opacity transition for Chrome in Windows but it does not seem to be working.

My test HTML is:

```
<div class="box box-back">
</div>
<div class="box box-front">
</div>
```

And my CSS is:

```
div.box {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 75px;
}
div.box-back {
    background-color: yellow;
}
div.box-front {
    background-color: blue;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
div.box-front:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eL3r1cjq/).

This works in Safari, Firefox and Chrome on the Mac but in Chrome on Windows it has no effect for me. Is this a problem or is it my machine?

Comment: You don't have to [**prefix transitions**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions), also, your fiddle works just fine for me (Chrome,Windows). :)

Comment: Works fine for me (Chrome, Windows).

Comment: Thanks guys, I restarted my machine and now it's fine - no idea what was going on there. I'll probably delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the same as chromium [issue 451756](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=451756) and the same issue reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28264789/2433501).

It appears to be fixed in Chrome version 40.0.2214.115.