# Chrome won't display CSS transitions properly. How can I fix this?

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, transition

I am creating a static website and I tried putting a background-color transition on a button. I checked my code several times and then I realized that it's not my code. The whole browser displays CSS transitions poorly. Some don't animate at all, some only show the initial and final stage after I click on them several times. I tried visiting the same sites from my computer and from different computers and I'm sure it's my browser's fault.

I emptied the cache and deleted the cookies. What can I do to fix this problem?

**EDIT:** Here is my code

```
<p id="more"><a href="#">Read more</a></p>

#more a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-left: 2px solid #1bb2b2;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    transition: background-color 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 2s ease-in-out;
}

#more:hover a { color: white; background-color: #1bb2b2;}
```

**EDI2:** Just downloaded Firefox and the transition on my site and on every other site work perfectly. What is wrong with my Chrome?

Comment: I'd suggest posting your code or providing a JSFiddle that shows the problem. The following JSFiddle works for me in the latest version of Chrome (hover over the red box): http://jsfiddle.net/Lwe2kgm1/1/

Comment: Add some code to your answer...

Comment: I hover over the box, nothing happens.
I'll post the code in a minute if it matters, but even if my code is wrong, and it might be cause I just started learning, something must be wrong with my browser if no transition plays correctly.

Comment: Have you tried another browser to verify your code works? The fiddle I provided should work in the latest version of Firefox as well. EDIT: Tried your code (http://jsfiddle.net/ccbkadpu/) and it works for me in Chrome 40 just fine. You might want to give Chrome a good old reboot or reinstall. :)

Comment: I just downloaded Firefox and it works PERFECTLY!

What can be wrong with my Chrome?

Comment: I just reinstalled Chrome and it is still not working. I think I'll switch to Firefox until I find a fix.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an answer for you, but I'm pretty sure that this is the same problem that I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28206401/2433501). Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eL3r1cjq/5/) - the yellow box should fade to blue on hover. Does it work for you? It works fine for me in firefox and chrome on the mac but not in Windows. Strangely it seems to work after a reboot but if I hibernate and wake the machine it then doesn't work again.

Comment: I switched to Firefox a few days ago because Chrome refused to work even after I reinstalled it. Now I checked and it works fine on every website. Too bad I got used to Firefox now.

Comment: Check this : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=451756 Actually, transition on Chrome don't work. Try Firefox or Chrome Canaray. I don't understand why Google guys are taking too many time to release a  fix when they have fixed it on Canary.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the same as chromium [issue 451756](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=451756) and the same issue that I asked about in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28206401/2433501).

It appears to be fixed in Chrome version 40.0.2214.115.